# Removing pound symbol from string not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple task of removing any pound signs from a string, however it is simply not working.

I have googled the problem and followed other examples, but none of them have solved my problem.

If someone could give me some advice that would be great.

Thanks!

CODE:

```
var newWeight = optionWeight.options[optionWeight.selectedIndex].text;
alert(newWeight.replace("£", ""));
```

newWeight would be formatted like so : "110g (£3.00)"

Comment: `.text` - is this correct? Perhaps I'm wrong, but I would have thought this should be `textContent`?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or plnkr?

Comment: if "optionWeight.options[optionWeight.selectedIndex].text " doesn't give the formatted value as you said then it will not work. so it depends on your html, can you please show your html

Comment: It is quite difficult to create a fiddle as alot of the HTML is echoed from a php script unfortunately

Comment: .text is fine yes, it reads the text of my options

Comment: `"110g (£3.00)".replace("£", "")` this will work. but i guess your newWeight  variable is not having right value

Comment: [Nothing wrong with the replace](http://jsfiddle.net/14a1o21o/1/), so there must be something wrong with the HTML.

Comment: debug and check whether your newWeight value is proper.

Comment: My newWeight variable has the right value, when I alert it to the screen it appears fine.

Comment: `newWeight = newWeight.replace("£", "")` and then `alert(newWeight)`

Comment: @RGraham This is correct `HTMLOptionElement` has property `text` which is option text content.

Comment: @dfsq Just found it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement#Properties), wasn't very easy :) Anyway, the code works: http://jsfiddle.net/da47hLLp/

Comment: @CallumHolden are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No, there are no errors whatsoever. I just inspected the script element and found that when I am making a call to replace, it is formatted like so:replace("Â£", ""); Could this be why?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that there is more than one pound sign and you have to cater for them all.

Also the encoding of the page affects it, as does the encoding of the database column that you may have retrieved the string from.

Sometimes, the pound sign is represented by two characters.

Comment: "The problem is that there is more than one pound sign and you have to cater for them all." How can you say that without looking at the HTML?